# Returning value from restAPI in php, echo value not showing

Tags: php, html, json, api

I'm trying to return a value from my API using PHP, api can be found here:

code is as follows:

Im not seeing the echo on my page, don't see any errors and I believing im reading the json in correctly. Any help appreciated!

```
        <?php

        $titleid = 2;
        $url = "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi.php?id={$titleid}";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);



        $returnvalue = json_decode($response, true);

        echo $returnvalue["Age"];

        ?>
```

Comment: It looks like the server side response is not valid json, from what I can see. Is it possible to fix that on the server side?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? Apologies for the ignorance

Comment: Hi Kyle, no problem about explaining! I've added some explanation to my answer below, if that helps! Basically, the server output seems to add a line of text in front of the json data. If you know of a way to remove that extra "connected to db" text on your server `buildapi.php` file, it should help keep the json data valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the json is not valid on the server side (due to the "connected to db" text in front of the `{}` part). I think it would be a good idea to fix the server side response json data, if possible!

For now, here is a way to get the value it looks like you are intending to retrieve:

```
<?php
    $titleid = 2;
    $url = "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi.php?id={$titleid}";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $adjusted_response = str_replace('connected to db', '', $response);
    $returnvalue = json_decode($adjusted_response, true);
    echo $returnvalue['tv_shows']['Age'];
?>
```

Output:

```
$ php example.php
16+
```

If the server side json data is fixed, I think you could shorten the code to something like this:

```
<?php
    $titleid = 2;
    $url = "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi.php?id={$titleid}";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $returnvalue = json_decode($response, true);
    echo $returnvalue['tv_shows']['Age'];
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by server side json isn't valid? Apologies for the ignorance! Your method did return the value, what exactly is the adjusted_response doing?

Comment: In your `buildapi.php` file's output, there is text at the front of the response that reads "connected to db". If you have the opportunity to change that `buildapi.php` file so that the extra "connected to db" text isn't printed to the output, the json data should be valid. In my example, `$adjusted_response` is removing that extra "connected to db" text from the response. But this is probably not an ideal way to deal with the problem. If you change the server file to not include an echo or print type of statement for that first part, the example code at the end of my answer should work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, in the file I used to build my api I included the connection.php file I had created to connect to the database this included an echo "connected to db". Just removed that echo and its working perfectly now. Thanks for your help and explanation, hadn't realised it was returning a string. Understand completely now rather than my code just working! Appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that $response is returned as string , in order to fix that you need to edit your backend and make it give the response without "connected to db"

Comment: Hi @kylemoffett. If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.